# publish gradle plugin to jcenter fail

Tags: java, gradle, bintray, jcenter

This is message I received from jcenter:

> JCenter hosts Java applications that follow the Maven convention.
>   In addition to the .aar file, your version should include a pom file, a *-sources.jar, and optionally a *-javadoc.jar. Your files should be under a Maven path layout.
>   (see https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_includingyourpackagesinjcenter.html)

This is my project which I try to upload to jcenter:

https://dl.bintray.com/leaking/maven/com/quinn/hunter/hunter-linelog-plugin/0.8.5/

Comment: maybe because the dependency in the library have not be published to jcenter ?

Comment: Dependencies shouldn't have any impact. You got this message after clicking the 'include to JCenter' button?